# Get category URL with Url Rewrites Rules by Category ID

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

I have categories with Url Rewrites Rules. For example, base url for category MyTest = /mytest. But with rewrite rule url = /new-mytest. If I use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory - I get base url (/mytest). How can I get finally url for my categiry?

Answer (score 1):

Magento's URL rewrite engine is a great tool for improving SEO, as well as managing URLs. When you want to get the correct URL for a category based on the rewrite rules, you need to query the URL rewrite model, not just the category collection.

Here's a code snippet that shows how to get the URL by a category ID, taking into account the URL rewrites:

```
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite as UrlRewriteData;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class GetCategoryUrl
{
    protected $urlRewriteFactory;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->urlRewriteFactory = $urlRewriteFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function getUrlByCategoryId($categoryId)
    {
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $urlRewrite = $this->urlRewriteFactory->create();
        $urlRewrite->loadByData([
            UrlRewriteData::ENTITY_ID => $categoryId,
            UrlRewriteData::ENTITY_TYPE => 'category',
            UrlRewriteData::STORE_ID => $store->getId()
        ]);

        return $urlRewrite->getRequestPath() ? $store->getBaseUrl() . $urlRewrite->getRequestPath() : false;
    }
}
```

Here, we use the `Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory` to create a URL rewrite object and load it by data that includes the category ID, entity type 'category', and store ID. If a rewrite exists, it returns the modified URL; otherwise, it returns `false`.

Remember to instantiate your class properly and pass the category ID to the `getUrlByCategoryId` method.

Make sure to clear cache and regenerate di after adding this class in your module.

Comment: Script return error - Invalid method Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite::loadByData

Answer (score 0):

Hamendra, thanks for your answer!
I have adjusted your answer to my situation, because your script returns "Invalid method Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite::loadByData"

Also in my case, there is no need to check the store

```
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite as UrlRewriteData;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;

class GetCategoryUrl
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $urlFinder;

    public function __construct (
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
    ) {
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
    }

    public function getUrlByCategoryId($categoryId) {
        $rewrite = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData([
            UrlRewriteData::ENTITY_ID => $categoryId,
            UrlRewriteData::ENTITY_TYPE => 'category'
        ]);
        $targetPath = (!$rewrite) ? false : $rewrite->getRequestPath();

        return $targetPath;
   }
}
```